# How can I make Bitcoin start with a simple `bitcoind` in the terminal?

Tags: bitcoind, linux

When I want to start Bitcoin I have to use `/opt/bitcoin/bin/bitcoind` to start it. How can I use simply  `bitcoind` to start it?

I am using `centOS 7`.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19720475/1364089

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is correct but doesn't explain anything to the user as to why they can't just type `bitcoind` in the first place. This doesn't help people at all and future people will just follow this blindly.

To understand why some commands can be typed in without the full path you must understand the `$PATH` environment variable. A very good writeup on it was done here http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html.

A short explination is that `$PATH` lets you define what paths on your computer are searched for executable files. You can see what the current searched paths are by typing `echo $PATH` into your terminal. Here is an example from mine.

```
echo $PATH
/Users/mschuett/Uber/phacility/arcanist/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/mschuett/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Each directory is separated by a `:` and if a path at `/Users/mschuett/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` both included a binary called `test-command` it would always use the test command found in `/Users/mschuett/bin` since it comes first in the $PATH string. To add more directories to your $PATH you can simply write..

```
export $PATH=$PATH:/opt/bitcoin/bin
```

Now all executables at this path are available without typing the full path. To see what path an executable is being run from you can use `which bitcoind` and it will output the full path that is used when you run `bitcoind`.

Hope this helps actually explain what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: sudo `ln -s /opt/bitcoin/bin/* /bin`

I found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/q/19720475/1364089

Thanks to https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/5406/murch

Comment: Then don't just link it here, rather put your solution here and additionally link it! :)

Comment: you could also add /opt/bitcoin/bin to your $PATH

Comment: This is not useful as it doesn't show why this works and it also shows that you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how your OS works. I have written up a better explanation below.